# Outlook REST API to extract URLs in the message body

Tags: outlook-restapi

Is there an Outlook REST API that gives me all the urls extracted from the body of the message? Some thing like what EWS's EntityExtractionResult does?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. However, you can retrieve extended properties, so you should be able to request the [PidNameExtractedUrls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968646(v=exchg.80).aspx) property.

If you dig through those open specs, you should find these details on `PidNameExtractedUrls`:

```
Property set: PSETID_XmlExtractedEntities {23239608-685D-4732-9C55-4C95CB4E8E33}
Property name: XmlExtractedUrls
```

So that would mean I could make the following request (assuming you're using the Outlook endpoint, not Graph):

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String {23239608-685D-4732-9C55-4C95CB4E8E33} Name XmlExtractedUrls')
```

> For Graph, you would replace `PropertyId` with `id`.

That will include something like this in the message entities that have this property set:

```
"SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
        "PropertyId": "String {23239608-685d-4732-9c55-4c95cb4e8e33} Name XmlExtractedUrls",
        "Value": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><UrlSet><Version>15.0.0.0</Version><Urls><Url StartIndex=\"0\"><UrlString>https://www.google.com</UrlString></Url><Url StartIndex=\"23\"><UrlString>https://developer.microsoft.com/outlook</UrlString></Url></Urls></UrlSet>"
    }
]
```